# Determine if possible to connect all users to cell tower? [polynomial time algorithm]

Tags: algorithm

Given:
**users** u1,...,um
each users is given: **list of cell towers a user may connect** {s1,...sn}

**cell tower** c1,....cn
each cell tower is given : **capacity cp**

**Problem: Is it possible to connect all users to cell towers without exceeding capacity?**

My approach:

```
if sum(total_cell_capacity) < sum(total_users): 
    return false  #Joy Z's idea

sort users by number of available towers to them (ascending order)  
for each user:
    if user only have one tower availble to them:
        if tower is not full:
            allocate user to the tower
            tower_capacity --
        else:
            return false
    else:
        choose cell tower with biggest current capacity:
            allocate user to the tower
            tower_capacity --
return true
```

Would this yield polynomial time? Would this algo solve the problem at least?

*I am trying to learn how to write better on stackoverflow.
*please fix any errors I made.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to define what language you intend to write your code in.  What you are asking can be done with arrays in almost any language.  For example create an array of cell towers. and then each tower itself can be an array containing the data you need like current capacity and total_capacity

Comment: You can do a trivial reject in linear time:  If total users exceeds total capacity, you know you can't succeed.  If that trivial reject test says that allocation is not impossible, then you're left with something that resembles a graph coloring problem.  FWIW, your algorithm looks plausible, although my gut says you should fill up the most-constrained towers first...

Comment: @Narrim : I don't see why a viable algorithm couldn't be explored and analyzed in pseudo-code.  Heck, that's how all of Knuth's Art of Computer Programming books are written.  (Only once the algorithm's analyzed does he give something in MIX or MMIX.)

Comment: @Joe Z, Thanks for the linear reject. Didn't think of that. By most constrained towers, you mean towers that have the smallest capacity left?

Comment: @Lola : Yes, I mean start with the smallest towers first, perhaps picking the customers that have the fewest options ahead of customers with more options.  I don't know that guarantees a solution, but my gut feel leans in that direction.  This feels like something between a dynamic programming problem and a graph coloring problem.

Comment: @JoeZ, yes it is. Thanks for taking your precious time, I'll have to draw some examples.

Comment: @Lola:  You might look up the multiple-knapsack problem, and modify it so that various subscribers can only be considered against specific knapsacks (ie. towers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This reduces to the maximum cardinality matching problem, and can be solved in *O(maxCp mn Sqrt(m + maxCp n))* time using the [Hopcroft-Karp algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopcroft%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm). If *maxCp* is bounded that reduces to *O(mn Sqrt(m+n))*.

In detail: define a set of user nodes *U = {u1, u2, .., um}* and  a set of cell tower slot nodes

```
C = {c11, .., c_{1,cp(1)}, c_{2,1}, .., c_{2,cp(2)}, .., c_{n, 1}, c_{n, cp(n)}
```

Now add an edge between each user node and the node for each cell tower slot she can connect to, forming a bipartite graph. Your problem then reduces to the question of whether the maximum cardinality matching in the graph is of size *m*. If it is, every user can be connected to some cell tower slot. If it isn't, it must be less than *m* (it can't be more because we've only got *m* user nodes).

Given a bipartite graph of *V* nodes and *E* edges, the Hopcroft-Karp algorithm solves the maximum cardinality problem in time O(E Sqrt(V)). Since we have at most *maxCp mn* edges and at most *maxCp n + m* nodes, we get a runtime of *O(maxCp mn Sqrt(maxCp n + m))*.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the assignment problem again. Each user is a job that needs doing. For each cell tower, create a number of workers according to its capacity. The list of cell towers a user can connect to tells you which worker can do which jobs without incurring a penalty. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem tells you how to solve this/minimize the penalty with e.g. the Hungarian algorithm.